# How to update state after async dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-thunk

Assume my redux store retrieves data from some url using async thunk. Knowing this, how could I update the local state "users" to be equal to the value from the store(usersStore) after the store value has been updated/fetched?

"users" equals to initialState of userSlice which is just an empty array [].

I thought of handling that update in useEffect like below, but maybe there's a better solution?

Possible solution:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    setUsers(usersStore);
  }, [usersStore]
);
```

Component:

```
export const Users = () => {
  const usersStore = useSelector(state => state.users);
  const [users, setUsers]= useState(usersStore); //initially is just []

  useEffect(
    () => {
      dispatch(getUsersAsync());
    }, []
  );

  ...
```

Slice:

```
const initialState = [];

const getUsersAsync = createAsyncThunk('users/getUsersAsync', async () => {
  const res = await fetch('someUrl');
  const data = res.json();
  
  return data;
});
}

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getUsersAsync.fulfilled, (state, { payload: users }) => {
      return users;
    }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do what your were doing with this:

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    setUsers(usersStore);
  }, [usersStore]
);
```

If you want to store a local state that may be out of sync with your redux state, this would be the way to do it.

**However**

It might be better to just get rid of this:

```
const [users, setUsers]= useState(usersStore);
```

Since you're using this:

```
const users = useSelector(state => state.users);
```

Just reference this above for everything regarding your users and if you want to update that state at all you can just dispatch an action to do so.

Comment: I need the users to be a state so I could modify the data of the users without dispatches

Comment: Then your useEffect strategy should be fine.